# I can't add buildFeatures {viewBinding; true} to build.gradle.kts shows an error"Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)"

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, build.gradle

```
buildFeatures {
    viewBinding true
}
```

I try to add *View binding in build.gradle.kts.**I can't add buildFeatures {viewBinding; true} to build.gradle.kts shows an error"Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)"*

Comment: You can use `buildFeatures { viewBinding = true }` in `build.gradle.kts`.

Comment: thanks. but why is it shown differently in the android documentation?

Comment: Gradle build scripts may be written in `groovy` or `kotlin` language. Your example was written in `groovy` but placed into a kotlin script file. In `kts` files, you should use kotlin. https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/migrating_from_groovy_to_kotlin_dsl.html

Answer (score 0):

The `buildFeatures` block in the `build.gradle.ktx` file is used to enable or disable certain build features. In the code snippet you provided, `viewBinding true`
is used to enable view binding for your project but in `build.gradle` aka Groovy

So you must add `=` sign when you are using `build.gradle.ktx` like this:

```
buildFeatures {
    viewBinding = true
}
```

Regarding the difference between the syntax of build.gradle and build.gradle.ktx, the latter is a Kotlin DSL (Domain Specific Language) file that provides a more concise and type-safe way of writing Gradle build scripts. The syntax of build.gradle.ktx is different from that of build.gradle because it is written in Kotlin, whereas build.gradle is written in Groovy.

Documentation : https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#kts